# How to extract point coordinates of a segment contour in U2-Net?

Tags: coordinates, object-detection, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I wonder how to extract point coordinates of a segment contour in U2-Net segmentation image, for example, I want to find the contours of a person, how can I convert the segment image into a .npy or .json file? The segment image is like that.

[image: 1]

I want to find a way to convert the segmentation image into a file consists of contour point coordinates.